# ResponsiveSlides - I can't handle css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to use responsiveslides.js. It works but I don't know how to change css to get slider 100% width and no margins. Can someone help me?
Heres responsiveslides.css

```
.rslides {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  }

.rslides li {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  }

.rslides li:first-child {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  }

.rslides img {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  }
```

In the body i have:

```
<div id="sliderdiv">
                <ul class="rslides" id="slider1">
                <li><img src="../css/images/one.jpg" alt=""/></li>
                <li><img src="../css/images/two.jpg" alt=""/></li>
                <li><img src="../css/images/three.jpg" alt=""/></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

with

`#sliderdiv{
        width: 100%;
        height: 300px;
        padding: 0px;
    }`

Now it looks like this:

http://oi61.tinypic.com/2hgwac4.jpg

Comment: What is **![#sliderdiv** ?

Comment: that was typing mistake, sorry, corrected

Answer (score 0):

Try this it may work

```
.rslides img {
display: block;
height: auto;
float: left;
width: 100%;
border: 0;
}
```

Because the height will be auto , Example: 250px; and will remain the same.

Comment: This the same what is posted above.

Answer (score 0):

You might have a maxwidth set in the options.

```
$(".rslides").responsiveSlides({  
    maxwidth: "", <- LOOK FOR THIS
});
```

If that is the case, removing that line should fix this issue.

Comment: Thats not help. I have removed it and in the css set width 100% and height 20% and it made banner big for a half screen size height and almost full width(there are margins).